# Discord community bot for our FiveM server that handles the discord roles

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to create a discord community bot for our FiveM server that handles the discord roles.
I want the bot to restrict that ROLECHANNEL, so only the role commands can be posted. Other trash i want deleted so the channel stays clean.

The command is working and the role is assigned, but the bot also fires `message.reply('Wrong role, type ' + prefix +'roles');`  Why?

```
client.on('message', message => {

if (message.channel.id === ROLECHANNEL) {
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    if (!message.content.includes("fivem", "ark", "arma3", "roles", "stream",)) {
        message.delete([1]);
        message.reply('Wrong role, type ' + prefix +'roles');
    }
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "fivem")){
        message.delete([1]);
        let fivemrole = message.member.guild.roles.find("name", "fivem");
        message.member.addRole(fivemrole);
        message.channel.send('Gives ' + message.author + ' fivem role...');

    }
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "arma3")){
        message.delete([1])
        let armarole = message.member.guild.roles.find("name", "Arma3");
        message.member.addRole(armarole);
        message.channel.send('Gives ' + message.author + ' Arma3 role...');

    }
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "ark")){
        message.delete([1]);
        let arkrole = message.member.guild.roles.find("name", "Ark");
        message.member.addRole(arkrole);
        message.channel.send('Gives ' + message.author + ' Ark role...');

    }
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "stream")){
        message.delete([1]);
        let streamerrole = message.member.guild.roles.find("name", "Streamer");
        message.member.addRole(streamerrole);
        message.channel.send('Gives ' + message.author + ' Streamer role...');

    }
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "roles")) {
        message.delete([1]);
        message.channel.send('Help: ' + message.author + ' roles are. ' + roles);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem in this part `!message.content.includes("fivem", "ark", "arma3", "roles", "stream",)`
because message includes listen only fist argument "fivem",  you need add `or` block to your code

**V2**

As fist variant:

```
if(!message.content.includes("fivem") && !message.content.includes("ark") && !message.content.includes("arma3"))
```

or you can set allowed varible array and check it

```
    let allowedCommands = ["fivem", "ark", "arma3", "roles", "stream"]
if (!allowedCommands.find(command => message.content.indexOf(command) !== -1)) {
    message.delete([1]);
    message.reply('Wrong role, type ' + prefix +'roles');
}
```

Comment: `if (!message.content.includes("fivem" || "ark" || "arma3" || "roles" || "stream",))`
Like so?

Comment: I wrote some examples in my answer :)

Comment: Many thanks, that was a good work-around. Solved the problem.

Comment: glad to help :)